# добавить одно значение в List, находящийся в TValue Dictionary

Tags: c#

для начала инициализирую словарь:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dc = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
string tempKey = default;
```

нужно записать в словарь значение, если оно соответствует ключу, если ключа нет, то надо создать новую пару TKey-TValue

```
public void WriteDataDictionary(string data)
{
   tempKey = data.Substring(0, 1);
   if (dc.ContainsKey(tempKey) != true)
   {
      dc.Add(tempKey, new List<string>(){data}); //добавляю data во вновь созданную пару                   
   }
   else
   {
      //как добавить значение в массив List<string> по ключу.
   }
}
```

нашел ответ, как передать другой массив, а как добавить значение в массив не нашел

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
dc[tempKey].Add(data);
```

Comment: Ахахаха, глупо сейчас себя чувствую, спасибо, помогло